# File Access only via my ASP.NET App not directly in browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2003

I'd like to save images in a directory on my Disk in Windows Server 2003 in a Subfolder out of my webroot. 
   mydomain.com/myfolder

I'll upload images there for example test.jpg, which I'd like to show using ASP.NET, well this works, and If I try to browse the path "mydomain.com/myfolder" there is shown Access Denied.

My problem is, if I type "mydomain.com/myfolder/test.jpg" the picture is shown, but I'd like to show them only via my ASP.NET App.

Can I manage this using the Windows Server permissions without using the Active Directory Authentication Mode?

I tried for example to left only the NETWORK SERVICE put then also my .NET app didn't show the image anymore.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance
Johannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Wildcard Application Mappings](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/ad520e25-877c-4764-bfe5-a9d5a9a5d3bb.mspx?mfr=true) to map all requests (.*) to aspnet_isapi.dll.
Then you can control all requests by ASP.NET. You can write e.g. HttpModule, that will handle showing your image.

In IIS7 you can use attribute

```
runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"
```

in web.config in element:

```
<system.webServer><modules>
```